# Squeeze the data.table if there are NA in the rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` which has lots of `NAs`. I want to squeeze the `data.table` so that it can be represented in a compact way

```
dt <- data.table(id=1:5, c('x',NA,'y',NA,'y'), c(NA,NA,NA,NA,'z'), c('y','z','y','x',NA))
dt
>   id V2 V3 V4
>1:  1  x NA  y
>2:  2 NA NA  z
>3:  3  y NA  y
>4:  4 NA NA  x
>5:  5  y  z NA
```

The output I am looking for is

```
dt
>   id V2 V3
>1:  1  x y
>2:  2  z NA
>3:  3  y y
>4:  4  x NA
>5:  5  y  z
```

Comment: Something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639599/remove-leading-nas-to-align-data (there is also a `data.table`-answer) But you want to do it for rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We group by "id", `unlist` the "Subset of Data.table" (`.SD`), remove the "NA" with `na.omit`, create a sequence column by 'id', and then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dt[, na.omit(unlist(.SD)) , id][, N:= paste0("V", 1:.N), id], id~N, value.var="V1")
#    id V1 V2
#1:  1  x  y
#2:  2  z NA
#3:  3  y  y
#4:  4  x NA
#5:  5  y  z
```

Or we can use `melt` (as @Frank suggested)

```
melt(dt, id = "id", na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice. In my opinion, they should stop at `dt[, na.omit(unlist(.SD)) , id]` which is roughly equivalent to `melt(dt, id = "id", na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score -1):

```
dt$v2 <-ifelse(is.na(dt$v2),dt$v4,dt$v2)
dt$v3[1] <- replace(dt$v3[1],is.na(dt$v3[1]),dt$v4[1]) 
dt$v3[3] <- replace(dt$v3[3],is.na(dt$v3[3]),dt$v4[3]) 
dt$v4 <- NULL
```